# How to fix package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’ on MacOS

Tags: java, r, macos

I tried to connect to my company's SQL database using a code that works on a friend's computer that works with me.

But I face the message below when trying to run the rJava and RJDBC libraries.

This is my JRE version:

```
java --version
java 13 2019-09-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I've tried to reinstall the packages after installing JRE but it didn`t work.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Users/samuel.medeiros/Library/R/3.6/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Users/samuel.medeiros/Library/R/3.6/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/samuel.medeiros/Library/R/3.6/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```